# How do I open a gif in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gif, animated-gif

I'm wondering if it's possible to play an animated gif using Python. I'd just like to display a set of them and iterate at a certain interval. I'm wondering what the best route to take to open them in python. Is it possible to open with Preview (I'm using a Mac) or perhaps a web browser package?

Comment: `import webbrowser; webbrowser.open('file:///path/to/image.gif')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Tkinter library in python. You can even add buttons, labels etc..

More Information:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

Comment: PhotoImage works on gifs, but does it work on _animated_ gifs?